# Entire div color and does not change at the time of hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, hover

I have made a div. Which contain image, text, and link. I want to give some hover effects on that div. This div background color is black. and font and link color are white. I want to make a div which color turns to red and link and text color turns to black at the time of hover. Also there will be a red overlay in the image. Currently only div text and background color change at the time of hover. I did not get any hover effects to images and link color remain red.

```css
CSS : 

    .card{
    background-color: #221F1F;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    
    }
    .card a{
    color: #D53F31;
    position: absolute;
 bottom: 40px;
 
    }
    .card:hover{
    background-color: #D53F31;
    color: #221F1F;
    
    }
```

```html
 <div class="card student" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img/card1.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="card-body">

                     <p class="card-text">Get an <br>affordable degree <br>in Europe</p>
                       <a href="#" class="card-link">Know More</a>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just select the  tag and  tag using

```
.card:hover a{
 /* css code */
}
.card:hover img{
 /* css code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a rule that targets the link when the card is hovered. try this:

```
.card:hover a{
  color:#221F1F
}
```